# Compute the time since the beginning of the week?

Tags: r

I have a bunch of datetime data and I'd like to see if there is any weekly pattern in it. So I'd like to compute the elapsed time (**in seconds**) since the beginning of the week with R.

How can I do that? I did the same thing for a daily pattern using `difftime(time,as.Date(time))` but I can't use the same trick for the week as there is no `as.Week()`.

Comment: take a look at the `lubridate` package.  Specifically the `wday` and `week` functions.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really solve my problem, since I'd like the precise time (in seconds) since the beginning of the week. The weekday isn't precise enough.

Comment: I didn't say it solved your problem, but I think `week` is exactly the `as.Week()` function you asked for.  Since you didn't provide any code, either your data or what you've tried, I didn't feel like creating an example and writing the code for you.  However, using those two functions plus time of day will let you see weekly fluctuations.

Comment: Is Monday or Sunday the first day of the week for you?

Comment: @TheodoreLytras: it doesn't matter, I'm just trying to make a plot. Make it Monday if you have to pick one.

Comment: @Justin: I showed how I proceeded for the elapsed time since the beginning of the day, but I don't have a clue on how to do the same with weeks. And no, week is not the as.Week() I asked for, since I can't do difftime(time,as.Week(time)). Of course that as.Week() wouldn't make sense, but I was just trying to explain myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in base R, and you already gave yourself the answer: `difftime()` with a proper offset.

Even midnight is good enough as you simply need to add dayOfTheWeek * 24 * 60 * 60 to is, and dayOfTheWeek is a field in `POSIXlt`.

If you want higher-end helper packages, my RcppBDT has a few functions from Boost Date_Time too.

Illustration:

```
R> now <- Sys.time()
R> midnight <- trunc(now, "days")   # elegant way to get midnight; thanks @flodel
R> today <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())
R> today$wday   # it is Sunday
[1] 0
R> 
R> difftime(now, midnight, unit="secs")
Time difference of 56630.6 secs
R>
```

So you could add `today$wday * 24 * 60 * 60`

```
R> as.numeric(difftime(now, midnight, unit="secs")) + today$wday*24*60*60
[1] 56630.6
R>
```

Comment: `midnight` should not be hardcoded, instead you can use `trunc(now, "days")`.

Comment: That is *very elegant* and a trick a had not used before.  Nice. Updating post.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution as well:

```
secs.in.week <- function(t) {
  d <- as.integer(format(t, "%w"))
  d <- ifelse(d, d-1, 6)
  weekstart <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(t)-d) - 2 * 3600  # Convert UTC -> Local time. I'm on UTC+2h
  as.numeric(difftime(t,weekstart), units="secs")
}
```